# gnome-open raises this error when run from inside tmux

Tags: gnome, tmux

The error I get is this:

```
GConf Error: Failed to contact configuration server; the most common cause is a missing or misconfigured D-Bus session bus daemon. 
See http://projects.gnome.org/gconf/ for information. 
(Details -  1: Failed to get connection to session: Error connecting: Connection refused)
Failed to open bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-BYC0LHrEHk: Connection refused
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of letting Gnome run `dbus-launch` to create a random D-Bus address, start `dbus-daemon` explicitly early in your X session startup and give it a fixed address like `unix:path=~/.dbus-$HOSTNAME-$DISPLAY`.

Given the information in the [bug report](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=582839), you may even be able to get away with `unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` and let applications find out the bus address from the root window properties.

As of 15.10, the per-session dbus instance is created via an [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) [session job](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#session-job). The job file in question is `/usr/share/upstart/sessions/dbus.conf`. You can replace the default random address by [overriding](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#override-file) the `pre-start script` stanza which specifies the address to use. Create `~/.config/upstart/dbus.override` with the following:

```
pre-start script
    DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=$HOME/.dbus-$(hostname)-$(echo $DISPLAY | sed -e s/:/%3A/)
    initctl set-env DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
end script
```

The fixed address will be used after you next log in.

Comment: What about on 16.04? The Upstart file is still present, so would it still work?

Comment: @Oxwivi This doesn't seem to have changed on 16.04, but I haven't tested.

Comment: Just to let you know, it does work.

Answer (score 3):

This is apparently a bug in gconf that already has a fix (if I understood correctly from this [bug report](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=582839)). In the meantime, the following should work around the problem:

```
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$(tr '\0' '\n' < /proc/$(pgrep -U $(whoami) gnome-session)/environ|grep ^DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=|cut -d= -f2-)
```

Answer (score 3):

Or if as me you don't use gnome:

`unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS`

Comment: Works for me, and I *do* use gnome!

Answer (score 2):

tmux can be told to always reset certain env vars:

> ```
> update-environment variables
>
> Set a space-separated string containing a list of environment variables to
> be copied into the session environment when a new session is created or an
> existing session is attached. Any variables that do not exist in the source
> environment are set to be removed from the session environment (as if -r was
> given to the set-environment command). The default is "DISPLAY SSH_ASKPASS
> SSH_AUTH_SOCK SSH_AGENT_PID SSH_CONNECTION WINDOWID XAUTHORITY".
> ```

Based on that it might be appropriate to add DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRES to this option in `~/tmux.conf`:

```
set-option -g update-environment "DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS DISPLAY SSH_ASKPASS SSH_AUTH_SOCK SSH_AGENT_PID SSH_CONNECTION WINDOWID XAUTHORITY"
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Didn't work for me (Ubuntu 10.04)...

Comment: Didn't work for me on Mint 15 :( ...what distro are you running?

Comment: I'm running Debian unstable, tmux version 1.8-4.